# asp.net Controller: how can I save data for a "history" table simultaneously with deleting a table with similar information?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm attempting to create a history page/table for my website, where when the User completes a workout the Current User Workout table deletes the Workout information upon completion (which is already functioning), AND a history table is updated with the identical fields + a DateTime so that the user can see previous workouts they have completed.

Currently, I am confused on how to implement this. My current "complete" function in the Controller looks like this:

```
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Complete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult CompleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            UserCurrWorkout userCurrWorkout = db.UserCurrWorkouts.Find(id);
            db.UserCurrWorkouts.Remove(userCurrWorkout);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

which is just CRUD code for deleting information in a table based on ID. What I wish to add to this is, very simply, something like:

```
            var oldWorkouts = new UserWorkoutHistory { UserId = model.UserId, UserOldWorkout = model.UserActiveWorkout };
            db.UserWorkoutHistories.Add(oldWorkouts);
```

just above the `db.UserCurrWorkouts.Remove` code. The “model” of my current workout database isn’t recognized in the function, however, how to make it so is my primary question unless there is a better approach.

Any information or tips would be greatly appreciated! Let me know if you would like to see any other code that may bring clarity to my issue!

EDIT: Here is UserCurrWorkout Model:

```
namespace Powerlevel.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

    [Table("UserCurrWorkout")]
    public partial class UserCurrWorkout
    {
        [Key]
        public int UCWId { get; set; }

        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public int UserActiveWorkout { get; set; }

        public virtual User User { get; set; }

        public virtual WorkoutExercise WorkoutExercise { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and UserWorkoutHistory model:

```
namespace Powerlevel.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

    [Table("UserWorkoutHistory")]
    public partial class UserWorkoutHistory
    {
        [Key]
        public int UWHId { get; set; }

        private DateTime Date = DateTime.Now;

        public DateTime CurrentTime
        {
            get { return Date; }
            set { Date = value; }
        }

        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public int UserOldWorkout { get; set; }

        public virtual User User { get; set; }

        public virtual WorkoutExercise WorkoutExercise { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to have done that! So what is your question?

Comment: Sorry! I didn’t word it accurately, that is what I WANT to do, however, the models for my CurrWorkout db aren’t being recognized inside that function, I’m hoping there’s something I can add to establish this connection

Comment: Please provide `UserCurrWorkout` and `UserWorkoutHistory` model classes.

Comment: Do you really need a 2nd table? Perhaps just add WorkoutCompleteDate as a nullable. Active workouts are `db.UserCurrWorkouts.Where(wo => wo.WorkoutCompleteDate != null)`

Comment: @SteveGreene I feel like this may cause me more problems (or more code changes) since I already have a view that displays a Users current workouts, and also want a separate view looking at the history table that displays their previously completed workouts

Comment: That is why they call them views :) Design the underlying tables for efficiency and normalcy, then present as needed. One would not have a separate table for open vs closed invoices as an example.

Comment: I agree with @SteveGreene. It would be more efficient to just flag a workout as completed than to copy all workout data to another table.

Comment: @SteveGreene that does sound more logical, I suppose if nothing works the way I am attempting to do it, it may be best to take your approach. It's just one of those things where I wish I had thought about it in hindsight because my project feels like a big monolith and I have to create updated tables, models, and controllers just to make a flag that confirms whether a workout is complete exist lol, I'm still new to asp.net so I rely on a lot of CRUD code to help me understand how things are working

Answer (score 1):

If I'm getting your point right, I think this is what you need:

```
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Complete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult CompleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        UserCurrWorkout userCurrWorkout = db.UserCurrWorkouts.Find(id);
        var oldWorkouts = new UserWorkoutHistory { UserId = userCurrWorkout.UserId, UserOldWorkout = userCurrWorkout.UserActiveWorkout };
        db.UserWorkoutHistories.Add(oldWorkouts);
        db.UserCurrWorkouts.Remove(userCurrWorkout);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

**Update**:
Also the foreign key `WorkoutExercise_LinkId` of `oldWorkouts` must in assigned in this line too:

```
var oldWorkouts = new UserWorkoutHistory { UserId = userCurrWorkout.UserId, UserOldWorkout = userCurrWorkout.UserActiveWorkout , WorkoutExerciseId = 'a valid key from WorkoutExercise table'};
```

**Update 2**:
Although, first you need to define a foreign key in the `UserCurrWorkout` entity and avoid EF to generate an fk column in the database that does not exist in the entity:

```
[Table("UserCurrWorkout")]
public partial class UserCurrWorkout
{
    [Key]
    public int UCWId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int UserActiveWorkout { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public int WorkoutExerciseId { get; set; } // The explicit foreign key
    public virtual WorkoutExercise WorkoutExercise { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: the code runs without issue, but I keep getting an error on the site when I attempt the delete/save process on the two tables, with the message being `Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'WorkoutExercise_LinkId'.` The WorkoutExercise table is linked the exact same way in both tables and doesn't get altered at all so I'm not sure why it is not recognizing the column name when I reach this point

Comment: You have a foreign key in your `UserWorkHistory` table called `WorkoutExercise_LinkId` that must be assigned with a valid key from the corresponding table when initiating `oldWorkouts` in the line `var oldWorkouts = new UserWorkoutHistory { UserId = userCurrWorkout.UserId, UserOldWorkout = userCurrWorkout.UserActiveWorkout };`

Comment: thats where I am confused, I don't have anything named `WorkoutExercise_LinkId`, I have a table called `WorkoutExercise` and it contains a `LinkId` value that `UserCurrWorkouts` successfully connects to. If I try typing `WorkoutExercise_LinkId = ...` to my controller it comes up with an error since it does not exist. I tried `var oldWorkouts = new UserWorkoutHistory { UserId = userCurrWorkout.UserId, UserOldWorkout = userCurrWorkout.UserActiveWorkout, WorkoutExercise = userCurrWorkout.WorkoutExercise };` but that resulted in the earlier error. I appreciate you helping me through this though!

Comment: The reason is that you have not defined an explicit foreign key to `WorkoutExercise` in your `UserWorkoutHistory` model, therefore EF has generated a column called `WorkoutExercise_LinkId` for the relationship in your database. The best practice is to recreated your database using a new migration and define an explicit foreign key and avoid EF to generate a column that does not exist in your entity.

Comment: I ended up going with altering the CurrWorkout table with a boolean marker as @SteveGreene suggested, it seems to be easier to process and code given my current knowledge. Thanks again!